# Can Application object get re-created while the app still running?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I have extended the `Application` object as `MyApplication` and the design is as follows

```js
public class MyApplication extends Application {
  
  private MyObject myObject;
  
  public MyApplication () {
    mInstance = this;
  }
  
  public static MyApplication getInstance() {
    return mInstance;
  }
  
  public MyObject getMyObject(){
    return myObject;
  }
  
  public setMyObject(MyObject object){
    myObject = object;
  }
}
```

I am accessing the `myObject` value in Activities as well as Services as `MyApplication.getInstance().getMyObject()`.  I don't see any issue with this normally, but in production for few users sometimes suddenly `getMyObject()` is returning `null` i.e getting reset. First I was under the impression that the OS might be killing and re-creating the app due to which I am observing null. I am not avoiding the memory low scenario, however if that is the case it should be killing the Activities and the Services too before destroying the `Application` object.

Inside an `Activity` I am keeping a reference of `MyApplication` as

`private MyApplication myApp = MyApplication.getInstance();`

So this is how my observation from logs regarding the `getMyObject()` value.

`myApp.getMyObject()` prints `!= null`

then a Service `MyService` gets called and inside that 
`MyApplication.getInstance().getMyObject()` prints `== null`

again back in the activity `myApp.getMyObject()` or `MyApplication.getInstance().getMyObject()` prints `!= null`

`myObject` has been initialized before printing these logs and in between these logs there is no `myObject` reset code getting called.

**Can it happen that the `Application` object got re-created but the `Acitivty` is still active?**
or
**Can Service get a different instance of `Application` than that of the `Activity` thread?**

As per my understanding in a app life-cycle `myApp` should always be equal to `MyApplication.getInstance()` as OS should maintain single instance of Application.

Note: Also would like to add that I am getting this un-usual behavior in Samsung Tab 4.

Comment: perhaps you are getting your object before setting your object!

Comment: That's not the case, though I missed to mention the myObject has already initialized and if it is null then the first myApp.getMyObject() should not print null.

Comment: where is the code that initialises `myObject`?

Comment: It happens before opening the Activity, and I can conform that the `myObject` is properly initialized and not null before I am trying to access.

Answer (score 1):

### Don't store Data in the Application Object

The applicataion object will **not** stay in memory forever. When a user sends your application to the background by e.g. pressing the home button the application object might be killed if the system requires the memory. This might happen after minutes but could take hours. When the user then resumes the application the application object might not be the same as before and `mMyObject` will be `null` if it has no initial value.

#### Solutions

Make `null` checks and act accordingly

Use some form of [data-storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Initialize your object in the application constructor

```
public MyApplication () {
    mInstance = this;
    mMyObject = new MyObject()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of it and have plan to move the object from Application, but it will take time to replace it, so I am looking for a intern solution to handle it and answer to the un-usual behavior of the Application object.

Comment: The behavior of the Application object is not unusual.
If you want a quick fix use either null pointer checks (which you should do anyway) or initialize `myObject` in the `MyApplication` construktor.

Answer (score 0):

You don't wanna have public constructor, but a onCreate() method.
You also want a static instance of the class.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

  private MyObject myObject;
  private static MyApplication mInstance;

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mInstance = this;
  }

  public static MyApplication getInstance() {
    return mInstance;
  }

  public MyObject getMyObject(){
    return myObject;
  }

  public setMyObject(MyObject object){
    myObject = object;
  }
}
```

And of course change your manifest to tell that's this is your class that will handle the application (if not done yet)

```
<application
        android:name="com.XXX.MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Comment: The XML is already there, yeh I think the constructor is not correct, it should be
`public MyApplication () {
    super();
    mInstance = this;
  }`
However will it matter if I move that to onCreate(), as in either the case the value of `this` should not be changing. Also if there is some assignment issue, it should fail every time.

Comment: Well basically you don't need a constructor as it will be the system that will create this object, calling the `onCreate` method. So this is where you need to retain the instance (`mInstance = this`).
If you need to set your object, just call `MyApplication.getInstance().setMyObject()`, same to retrieve it. That way, the mInstance will be unique and consistent the entire lifetime of your app.

Comment: Yes, I am planning to move that to onCreate(), however form the log what I see is there are two instances of Application object, is that possible?

Comment: Yes and no. I suppose what happens here is you have the "normal" instance that the system creates, and another as an object.
And since they're different, and you only set MyObject in one of them (obviously the one that you store), then it won't have a null MyObject, whereas the one that the Application created will have a null MyObject.   To make it more simple, you're dealing with 2 MyApplication objects, one handling your application, the other as a simple object

Comment: But I am no where creating an instance of `MyApplication` by explicitly calling `new MyApplication()`, I am just keeping a static reference in the constructor which will get called while OS create the object.